# Truncate data.frames in a list to the shortest length

Tags: r

I have some data like so:

```
df1 = (cbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,7)))
df2= cbind(c(1,2,5,8,1,7),c(1,2,5,8,1,7))
myls=list(df1,df2)
```

I'm looking for a way to chop df2 to the length of d1. This can be done just by cutting off any numbers at the end of df2. Hopefully the solution would also allow for more than 2 df in the list. The real data set has 1.4mill points and some varying amount of `dfs(df1,df2,df3....df(n)`. they all will only have 2 columns though`(y) and (x)`.

My guess is that `sapply(myls,'[',1)` will be used..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could also use the `head`

```
n <- min(vapply(myls, nrow, 0))
lapply(myls, head, n)
```

Comment: This seems to be the better solution! Works great!

Answer (score 1):

```
n <- min( sapply(myls, nrow ) )
lapply(myls, function(x){x[1:n,]})
```

Comment: Something about this code is actually not subsetting the data but replacing it with a vector from 1:n.

Comment: it works for your example; what example do you have where it doesn't?

Comment: When i run it in my example, I end up with a data frame of 4 columns and not 2 like I started with.

Comment: sorry, my impression was that you wanted to combine the data.frames. I edited my answer to just return a list of chopped dataframes.